# Multiple ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN in one SQL function call

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I came across some weird behaviour I'd like to understand.

I create a plpgsql function doing nothing except of ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN. I call it 2 times on the same table:

- A) In a single `SELECT` sentence
- B) In a SQL function with same `SELECT` as in A)

Results are different: A) creates two columns, while B) creates only one column. Why?

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_text_column(table_name text, column_name text) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $fff$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE '
        ALTER TABLE ' || table_name  || '
        ADD COLUMN  ' || column_name || ' text;
    ';
END;
$fff$
;
--  this function is called only in B
CREATE FUNCTION add_many_text_columns(table_name text) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $fff$
    WITH
    col_names (col_name) AS (
        VALUES
            ( 'col_1' ),
            ( 'col_2' )
    )
    SELECT  add_text_column(table_name, col_name)
    FROM    col_names
    ;
$fff$
;

-- A)
CREATE TABLE a (id integer);

WITH
col_names (col_name) AS (
    VALUES
        ( 'col_1' ),
        ( 'col_2' )
)
SELECT  add_text_column('a', col_name)
FROM    col_names
;
SELECT * FROM a;

-- B)
CREATE TABLE b (id integer);
SELECT add_many_text_columns('b');
SELECT * FROM b;
```

Result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE TABLE
 add_text_column
-----------------


(2 rows)

 id | col_1 | col_2
----+-------+-------
(0 rows)

CREATE TABLE
 add_many_text_columns
-----------------------

(1 row)

 id | col_1
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.4. Please note that this is only a minimal working example, not the full functionality I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION g(i INTEGER)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'g called with %', i;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
        SELECT g(id)
        FROM generate_series(1, i) id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

What do you think happens when I run `SELECT t(4)`? The only statement printed from `g()` is `g called with 1`.

The reason for this is your `add_many_text_columns` function returns a single result (void). Because it's SQL and is simply returning the result of a `SELECT` statement, it seems to stop executing after getting the first result, which makes sense if you think of it - it can only return one result after all.

Now change the function to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF VOID AS $$
        SELECT g(id)
        FROM generate_series(1, i) id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And run `SELECT t(4)` again, and now this is printed:

```
g called with 1
g called with 2
g called with 3
g called with 4
```

Because the function now returns `SETOF VOID`, it doesn't stop after the first result and executes it fully.

So back to your functions, you *could* change your SQL function to return `SETOF VOID`, but it doesn't really make much sense - better I think to change it to `plpgsql` and have it do a `PERFORM`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
        PERFORM g(id)
        FROM generate_series(1, i) id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That will execute the statement fully and it still returns a single `VOID`.

Answer (score 1):

[eurotrash provided a good explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814890/939860)

#### Alternative solution 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
   SELECT g(id)
   FROM generate_series(1, i) id;

   SELECT null::void;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Because, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html)

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning
>   the result of the last query in the list. In the simple (non-set)
>   case, the first row of the last query's result will be returned.

By adding a dummy `SELECT` at the end we avoid that Postgres stops after processing the the first row of the query with multiple rows.

#### Alternative solution 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
   SELECT count(g(id))
   FROM generate_series(1, i) id;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

By using an aggregate function, all underlying rows are processed in any case. The function returns `bigint` (that's what `count()` returns), so we get the number of rows as result.

#### Alternative solution 3

If you *need* to return `void` for some unknown reason, you can cast:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t(i INTEGER)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
   SELECT count(g(id))::text::void
   FROM generate_series(1, i) id;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

The cast to `text` is a stepping stone because the cast from `bigint` to `void` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the other answer, because it was earlier and both answers are very good.